# Не получается вывести картинку в шаблон

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

Делал простенький сайт без авторизации, куда мужно было заливать и просматривать картинки, сохранение реализовать получилось, но вот с выводом беда - вроде все сделано правильно, но сервер выдает ответ text/html, а не image/*

[image: Картинки]

[image: Ответ сервера]

**Шаблон, который выводит картинки:**

```
<#if posts??>
<#list posts as post>
    <div class="card text-white bg-secondary my-3">
        <img src="/img/${post.imageName}" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${post.title}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">${post.tag}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</#list>
</#if>
```

**Сам класс картинки:**

```
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private String imageName;
    private String tag;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

**MVC, который по идее должен перенаправлять с /img/** в файловую систему:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVC implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/" + uploadPath + "/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Вся пргограмма на гитхабе: [Тут](https://github.com/Vakarine/ImageBank.git)

Comment: Перейди по src картинки, если картинки не будет - неправильно выводишь. Скорее всего файла нету.

Comment: @Владислав При переходе по src почему-то выдается не картинка, а начальная страница, т.е localhost/, файлы сохраняются, я их у себя в папке в файловой системе вижу, так что вообще даже догадок нету

Comment: Вот, при переходе должна выдаваться картинка в браузере. Попробуй абсолютный путь. Скинь полную ссылку по которой ты переходишь на картинку.

Comment: @Владислав Нет, по абсолютному тоже не работает. Полная ссылка: localhost:8090/img/*Имя картинки.расширение*
Абсолютный путь: D:/courses/ImageBank/uploads

Comment: Смотри, абсолютный путь к картинке которую ты загружаешь в папку img.
http:://адрес_локального_сайта/img/имя картинки + расширение.
Что за папка uploads? 
Возможно путь должен быть /uploads/img/имя картинки.
У тебя явно что-то с путями напутано.

Comment: @Владислав  У меня `upload.path=D:/courses/ImageBank/uploads` и при обращении по удресу `/img/**` webMVC перенаправляет c `/img/**` к `D:/courses/ImageBank/uploads/**`

Comment: Значит неправильно перенаправляет, тяжело помочь не видя что происходит.

Comment: @Владислав я сейчас попытался с чистого листа начать - webMVC почему-то вообще не работает и ничего не делает соответственно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате он не работал потому что в

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String showInfoPage() {
        return "info";
    }
}
```

Нужно вместо @GetMapping писать @GetMapping("/"), иначе он как-то воздействует на WebMVC

Comment: Довольно простое решение)